# How to pass a variable modified with perl in find | xargs to the bash variables?

Tags: bash, perl, shell, xargs

```
COUNT=0
export  COUNT    
find "$SRCROOT" \(-name "*.h" -or -name "*.m") | xargs -0 perl -ne 'if (/$ENV{KEYWORDS}/){$COUNT++; print"Iteration number = $COUNT"}'
echo "Total Count= " $COUNT
```

This gives output as 
Iteration number = 0
Iteration number = 1
...
Iteration number = 25

Total Count= 0

Expected Total Count is 25(or some number based on resultset) but it always shows 0. The COUNT value modified in side loop is not retrieved after that.
How can i get the correct value of COUNT ?

Comment: The code in your question would not actually work - the closing paranthesis is not escaped  and `${KEYWORDS}` would be empty (unless perhaps you have aliased perl). Maybe there was a problem pasting it?

Comment: KEYWORDS is declared as shell variable and exported to use in perl which has assigned with a regex '(@"[^"]+")'

Comment: Why not just do the whole thing in perl?

Comment: i have only option to integrate shell script on legacy tool of my organization

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible for a child process (in this case `perl`) to change the environment of the parent process (your shell). What you can do though, is capture the output of the child process. Assuming the rest of the code is working as you expect, you can do this:

```
# replace ...'s with code from your sample
COUNT=$(find ... | xargs cat | perl -ne'if (...) { $COUNT++ } END { print $COUNT }' )
```

Notice that `$(..)` is used to capture the output of a command. Also notice that the only string printed is the `$COUNT` value in the end.

Comment: The above line works perfect in case of fetching count of one resultset. how can i get the results in case of having two variables for eg.. i m checking for 2 different patterns in files and iterating counter with ACOUNT and BCOUNT .   if(/$KEWORDS/){$ENV{ACOUNT}++}elsif(/$KEYWORDS@/){$ENV{BCOUNT}++}

Comment: please tell me if there is a different approach to get the desired output. But i have to use only shell

Comment: If you need data for multiple variables, then the solution would become slightly complicated. For example, in perl you can arrange for the output to be in this format:
COUNT 10
ACOUNT 5
BCOUNT 8

Then extract the values for the individual variables through grep or other string operations in your shell. I doubt there's an easier way.